# Add Admin Menu Inside Construct or Init

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu, settings-api

I thought I was making headway in my WordPress Development education until I ran across the Boilerplate for WordPress plugins and it uses a class object.  I'm fine with that and understand those concepts and I am a .Net developer.  But, for some reason, I cannot get any callback to function properly.  All I want at this point is an admin menu and when you click on that menu item, it display something like "PLEASE HELP ME!!!".  Check out what I have below and can anyone please explain what I have wrong?

```
class school_manager {
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
    }

    public function init(){
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add_admin_menu'));
        }

    public function add_admin_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'School Manager Settings', 'School Manager', 'administrator', 'school-manager-settings', 'show_admin_settings_page', null ); 
    }

    public function show_admin_settings_page(){
        echo '<p>This is a test for the admin settings page.  Please work!</p>';
    }
}
```

My new menu item does appear (as it did when I was not using a class object in my plugin architecture.  But, when I click on the menu item, I get the following error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First
>   argument is expected to be a valid callback,
>   'school_manager::create_admin_page' was given in
>   H:\root\home\xxxxx\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 406

I am trying to create a plugin that has not only an admin menu and submenu items, but also want to utilize the Settings API by trying to follow [this series](http://wp.tutsplus.com/series/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api/).  So, this is one of the crucial points to get something as simple as a menu item to function before I can continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback you have given in `add_menu_page()` is a static function, not a class method. It should be:

```
add_menu_page( 
    'School Manager Settings', 
    'School Manager', 
    'administrator', 
    'school-manager-settings', 
    array ( $this, 'show_admin_settings_page' )
);
```

And please don't use `&$this` anymore, that's PHP 4. :)

My demo plugin [T5 Admin Menu Demo](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Admin-Menu-Demo) might help understanding how that works.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  Your demo is great and well documented.  The only thing I noticed different is that you are calling the admin_menu action outside the class definition.  Will that matter if I have it inside or outside the class?  If not, I would prefer to keep in inside my init method.

Comment: @ClockwiseQ In my demo I don't need to call the class earlier than on `admin_menu`. If you need it you class instance earlier, do it. Just don't call your class on every request (for example on front end or AJAX requests, a common mistake).

Comment: +1 & a side question @toscho: I have so far always been going with `&$this` to ensure PHP4 compatibility, as well as analogously having a dummy constructor method with the same name as the parent class that in turn calls `$this->__construct();`. You reckon that's bullshit to do nowadays?

Comment: @JohannesPille WordPress does not work at all with PHP 4. Your plugin or theme code will never be called in PHP 4, so there is no point trying to be compatible.

Comment: @toscho No kidding, huh. I will lighten up a ton of my classes in the near future I suppose... Thx.